# Base of topology for metric-like space

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X$ be a nonempty set and $p:X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+ $ be a function satisfying the following conditions for all $x,y,z\in X$: \begin{align} &1)\enspace p(x,y)=0\implies x=y \\ &2)\enspace p(x,y)=p(y,x)\hspace{1,2cm}\\ \hspace{0,2cm}&3)\enspace p(x,z)\leq p(x,y)+p(y,z) \end{align}
Then the pair $(X,p)$
is said to be a metric-like space.

I want to show please that each metric-like $p$
on $X$ generates a topology $τ_p$ on $X$ whose base is the family of open-balls  $$B(x,\varepsilon)=\{y\in X:|p(x,y)-p(x,x)|<\varepsilon\}.$$

Thank you.

Comment: There is a typo in the question that makes it difficult to understand what is being asked, but if one replaces the $d$'s with $p$'s in the bottom part of the question, then an interesting question emerges. (@youssef: I think, but I'll have to check details, that the answer is no in general, but yes if $p$ is continuous.) I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @WillBrian As a follow-up to your edit I have also corrected a few minor typos and explicitly added to the post that this is different from metric space. (Since this can be missed if somebody does not read carefully.) A [quick Google search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q="metric+like+space") leads to the paper A. Amini-Harand: Metric-like spaces, partial metric spaces and fixed points, https://doi.org/10.1186/1687-1812-2012-204.

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin, does not reearch-level questions?!!

Comment: It seems that Wikipedia calls this a [metametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Metametrics).
A reference given there is Väisälä, Jussi (2005), "[Gromov hyperbolic spaces](http://www.helsinki.fi/~jvaisala/grobok.pdf)", Expositiones Mathematicae, 23 (3): 187–231, doi: [10.1016/j.exmath.2005.01.010](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.exmath.2005.01.010). From this paper:
"A metametric space is metrizable. In fact, a metametric $d$ can be changed to a metric $d_1$ simply by setting $d(x,x)=0$ and $d_1(x,y)=d{x,y}$ for $x\ne y$. Then $d$ and $d_1$ define the same topology."

Comment: @WillBrian Since it seems that you are a bit interested in the question (you mentioned that you voted that reopen), I wanted to let you know that I have posted the question (with some additional context) on another site: [Does metric-like space generate a topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2557780)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I have cast the final vote to reopen, so that you can put some of the details from your earlier comments into an answer below

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak,the definition of open ball is not same

Comment: You can find links to some basic info about comment replies, for example, [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/comment-notification/info). (In particular, they do not work if you add space after the @.)

Comment: BTW mentioning where you have taken the definitions in your question (metric-like, $B(x,\varepsilon)$ from would be, in my opinion, an improvement to the question. (A reasonable guess might be the paper I found in Google Scholar, but it is still just a guess.)

Comment: An analogous notion is the "mountain distance", a function $q(x,y)$ that shares all properties of a distance but symmetry (one example is the Hausdorff half-distance). Of course one can make a true distance  just symmetrizing it, $q(x,y)+q(y,x).$  The point is whether we really need to give these objects a name.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Yemon Choi's suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287864/base-of-topology-for-metric-like-space/#comment713456_287864) I am posting here an answer. So far it is mostly a summary of stuff which is was said in a post on [another site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557780/does-a-metric-like-space-generate-a-topology-if-open-balls-are-defined-as-b-si) and in the comments above. But if you have something to add (and it is not enough for a separate answer), feel free to edit this. (After all, this is [community wiki](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/community-wiki/info).)

A [quick Google search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q="metric+like+space") leads to the paper A. Amini-Harand: Metric-like spaces, partial metric spaces and fixed points, [doi.org/10.1186/1687-1812-2012-204](https://doi.org/10.1186/1687-1812-2012-204). This paper contains a definition of *metric-like space* in the same way as given in the question and contains a claim that the open balls, defined as above, indeed give a topology (without a proof).

**Counterexamples**

- [Does a metric-like space generate a topology if open balls are defined as $B_\sigma(X,\varepsilon)=\{y\in X; |\sigma(x,y)-\sigma(x,x)|<\varepsilon\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2557780) posted on Mathematics Stack Exchange contains a counter-example of a metric-like space on 3-points such that the open balls defined in this way do not give a topology.
- [mlk's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2557780#2557894) to the same question gives a wider class of counter-examples. If we choose any function $m\colon X\times X\to\mathbb R$ that is bounded, symmetric and fulfills $m(x,x)=0$, then the function given by $p(x,y)=m(x,y)+2M_0$ for $M_0=\sup |m(x,y)|$ is metric-like. Moreover, the open balls are exactly the sets $\{y\in X; |m(x,y)|<\varepsilon\}$. It is not difficult to find $m$ such that this does not give a topology.

**Related notions**

- As mlk points out [in their answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2557780#2557894), there is a related notion of *patrial metric*, which is also mentioned in Amini-Harand's paper. One of the reason for the problems might be that a different version of triangle inequality is needed. The definition of partial metric requires:

  - $x=y$ iff $p(x,y)=p(x,x)=p(x,y)$
  - $0\le p(x,x) \le p(x,y)$
  - $p(x,y)=p(y,x)$
  - $p(x,z) \le p(x,y)+p(y,z)-p(x,x)$
- The Wikipedia article on [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Metametrics) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Metric_(mathematics)&oldid=806227617#Metametrics)) contains a definition of *metametric* which is exactly the same as the above definition of metric-like function. The reference given there is: Väisälä, Jussi (2005), "[Gromov hyperbolic spaces](http://www.helsinki.fi/~jvaisala/grobok.pdf)", Expositiones Mathematicae, 23 (3): 187–231, doi: [10.1016/j.exmath.2005.01.010](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.exmath.2005.01.010). However, the topology in this paper is defined differently. (For example, a point $x$ is isolated whenever $p(x,x)>0$.)
- The Wikipedia article on metric also defines the notion of [premetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Premetrics) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Metric_(mathematics)&oldid=814963588#Premetrics)) where only conditions $d(x,x)=0$ and $d(x,y)\ge0$ are required. (Including the warning that this is not a standard term and terminology can vary). Clearly, $d(x,y)=|p(x,y)-p(x,x)|$ is a premetric. According to the Wikipedia article, every premetric gives a topology but in this way: A set $U$ is open if for every $x\in U$ there exist some ball $B(x,\varepsilon)=\{y\in X; d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$ with $B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$. It is explicitly mentioned that these balls are not necessarily open. (So the balls described here are not necessarily a base. And the topology is obtained from these balls in a different way than described in the linked paper.) This way of obtaining a topology is analogous to the way a topology is obtained from a metametric in Väisälä's paper.

Comment: An example of $m$ please

Comment: You should be able to find at least one example of $m$ based on the finite example in the linked question. Maybe somebody else will have some other suggestions - if you wish, we can also discuss this sometimes either in [general topology chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/15201/2017/12/11) or in [my chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2017/12/12).

Comment: @youssefsabar Only now I realized that you cannot talk in chat since you are [below 20 reputation points](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/chat). (To be more precise, you cannot talk in chat without help of moderators - at least until you gain sufficient reputation on one of the sites.) Still you can read transcripts, maybe some of the comments I've made in chat might be useful for you.